# CoreData prevent delete of defaults

Tags: cocoa, core-data, document

I have an entity in my coredata document based application.

I have certain default values that get created when a new document is created for that entity.

I need to be able to allow users to add and remove from that list (easily done), but prevent users from deleting the default values (cant find the answer).

---

Thanks for your response, that is a good option in this case I think I will use it.

I was wondering though if anyone knows how a person can VALIDATE a delete.... so if a person clicks on the delete button, it will go through some logic (complex or simple, depending on the application) then either ignore the click or actually delete the object.

I've looked at the method validateForDelete: but there is very little documentation on it and i'm not sure if this is the intended use of the method.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a boolean attribute to your entity that indicates whether or not a value is a default. You could then deactivate the delete button if the currently selected value is a default, using the `enabled` binding.