# CoreData prevent delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data

I've written [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569504/coredata-prevent-delete-of-defaults) but it was posted 3 years ago. So I want get up this topic.

I have some entities which have permanent records. And some entities which don't have them.
Interface for manage only one for those entities.
When I'm deleting record I don't know whether entity have permanent records or not. 
I want have something like to trigger on table in databases.

I tried overload *validateForDelete:* in my ManagedObject's class. I return NO when record is permanent.
TableView is binded to ArrayController and when I press button NSArrayController's method *remove:* is called. And my persistent record disappear. After that I try save result to persistent store and see my log message from *validateForDelete:* "You can't delete", but no error or exception.
I tried call *fetch:* and *rearangeObjects:*, but record is not visible. 
After restart App my record appear again.
I understand what it marked how is deleted and one way for return it - call rollback. But how can I understand what I have error when save result?

What is right way for realize this?

Comment: Thanks Mundi for interesting answer, but you hadn't read my question before it. 
I had read what sad Rob Keniger, but I didn't like this way. I don't want have handle on ArrayController's level. Please, will read accurate what I want.

Comment: Now I made it on ArrayController's level.

    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[arrayController selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([selectedObject respondsToSelector:@selector(persistent)] && [[selectedObject valueForKey:@"persistent"] isEqualTo:@1]) {
        NSLog(@"This is base type!!!!!!");
    }